Should I add the female pin headers to my KiCad PCB design?
I created a KiCad PBC design for my circuit:


The actual thing has (machined) female pin headers (and the ESP32-C3 and HX711 go on top of them):

I think the printed result will be the same whether or not I add the female pin headers to the design? Or maybe I'm wrong?

You could make this smaller by putting U1 on the bottom of the board, underneath U2. Use surface-mount headers if the through-hole ones would get in the way.

As long as the hole size is large enough to accommodate both, the layouts should be compatible.

@Hearth Ah, that sounds like a good idea. But I think there are no female pin headers that are taller than U1 (especially if U1 is mounted on female pin headers)? Or do you have a photo that illustrates this?

@wyc I'm talking about mounting U1 on the bottom of the board, upside down relative to U2.

@Hearth Ahh, sorry, I got it wrong. Good idea. Thanks, I'll play with that idea.

It will have the same holes and you'll be able to mount the same parts, yes. They will obviously be in the PCB itself and not embedded in a raised plastic part, so in that way it won't be exactly the same. You'll be soldering the parts onto the PCB instead of just inserting them into the headers. Otherwise the only real impact is if the HX711 or ESP32 has components on the underside, the female headers may have been preventing them from interfering with the PCB.
